Characterization of existence of vector potential
The following theorem is well known.

Theorem: Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^3$ be open and let a vector field $F \in C(\Omega; \mathbb R^3)$ be given. Then, the following are equivalent.

The field $F$ has a potential, i.e., there exists $f \in C^1(\Omega)$ with $F = \nabla f$.

For every curve $C \subset \Omega$, the line integral $\int_C F \cdot \mathrm{d} x$ only depends on the start point and the end point of $C$.

For every closed curve $C \subset \Omega$, we have $\oint_C F \cdot \mathrm{d} x = 0$.



The proof is not hard. For "2. $\Rightarrow$ 1.", one can argue as follows: In every connected component $\Omega_0 \subset \Omega$, we fix $x_0$ and define $f(x) := \int_{C_x} F \cdot \mathrm{d}x$, where $C_x$ is a curve from $x_0$ to $x$. One can check that $\nabla f = F$.
Now, it seems to be natural, to state a variant of the above theorem as follows.

"Theorem": Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^3$ be open and let a vector field $F \in C(\Omega; \mathbb R^3)$ be given. Then, the following are equivalent.

The field $F$ has a vector potential, i.e., there exists $H \in C^1(\Omega;\mathbb R^3)$ with $F = \operatorname{rot}H$.

For every oriented surface $\Sigma \subset \Omega$, the surface integral $\iint_\Sigma F \cdot \nu \, \mathrm{d} x$ only depends on the (oriented) boundary $\partial\Sigma$ of the surface $\Sigma$. Here, $\nu$ is the unit normal vector.

For every closed surface $\Sigma \subset \Omega$, we have $\oint\!\!\!\!\int_\Sigma F \cdot \nu \, \mathrm{d} x = 0$.



The implication "1.$\Rightarrow$2." follows from the Kelvin-Stokes theorem and
"2.$\Leftrightarrow$3." is not to hard.

Is the "Theorem" true and how to prove the missing direction?


In 3D you have to add a gauge to the vector potential $H$ and a boundary condition, the goal is to render the div-curl PDE system associated with this vector potential well-posed. If only existence not the uniqueness is concerned, the result holds.
Example: let $\phi$ solve the the following problem with whatever continuity needed in the context: for a nontrivial smooth $g$
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&\Delta \phi = 0\quad\text{ in }\Omega,
\\
&\phi = g \quad\text{ on }\partial\Omega.
\end{aligned}
\right.$$
Then $F = \nabla \phi$ is a vector field satisfying 3., but never a curl of a vector potential. The full argument can be done using the Helmholtz decomposition for $F$.

EDIT: I was wrong somehow misread the question only concerning about existence, as Kurt G. suggested. The example I gave applies to uniqueness.

Seems there is a gap. When $\Omega$ is a ball then we can use the Poincare lemma to conclude that the two-form $\omega=F_x,dy\wedge dz+F_y,dz\wedge dx+F_z,dx\wedge dy$ is exact. That is: there exists a one-form $\eta$ such that $\omega=d\eta$ in $\Omega,.$ Then $F$ is the curl of $\eta^\sharp,.$

@KurtG. You are correct. I was wrong and edited the answer.

This post is quite interesting. When $\Omega$ is such that the Poincare lemma applies (say, every closed surface can be contracted to a point) then OP's condition 3. allows to conclude that $F$ is divergence free, hence, the curl of an $A,.$ I find it astonishing that in the case of the well-known Theorem (scalar potential) $\Omega$ can be anything.
